# Effectively take batch of images and crop rectangular slices of images in numpy or tensorflow (batch image cropping)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I want to find a way to effectively do batch image cropping. The input image is the same. Each crop has different input offsets, height, and width.

Naive code:

```
img = np.zeros([100, 100, 3])
ofsets_x = np.array([10, 15, 18])
img_w = np.array([10, 12, 15])
ofsets_y = np.array([20, 22, 14])
img_h = np.array([14, 12, 16])

crops= []
for i in range(ofsets_x.shape[0]):
    ofset_x = ofsets_x[i]
    ofset_y = ofsets_y[i]
    w = img_w[i]
    h = img_h[i]

    crop = img[ofsets_x:ofsets_x + w, ofsets_y:ofsets_y + h, :] 
    crops.append(crop)
```

Because of this works very slow both in numpy and tensorflow(in tensorflow I am resizing each crop in the end of the loop to the specific size with tf.image.resize). In tensorflow I have tried also tf.vectorized_map and tf.while_loop - didn't gave me any significant speed boost. All this > 20x more slow then in C++. Crop is a simple
memcpy. It should be superfast especially with preallocated memory.

How to this faster in numpy or tensorflow?

Comment: Are you certain that cropping is the bottleneck, not the resizing? Your cropped images are of different sizes, so tf.image.resize (which is a much heavier operation) can't do with batch.

Comment: In numpy this is the best you can do.  Each crop has to a separate indexing operation.

Comment: @QuangHoang I have measured and to my surprise the cropping take ~ the same time as resizing( checked by  removing it). And I am using lanczos5 interpolation. Probably new tensor is created for every crop and that takes time. I have 60 slices on 16 1024 * 800 images on each step.

Comment: @I'mahdi Is ok, if it can use PILLOW Image.resize or other image resize

Comment: Just a little improvement: `crops = [img[x_start:x_end, y_start:y_end] for x_start, x_end, y_start, y_end in zip(ofsets_x, ofsets_x + img_w, ofsets_y, ofsets_y + img_h)]`

Answer (score 2):

I write code in [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) as you tag in your question. I create a datase with [tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset)  and use [map](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map). I check for **`5_000 images` and get `751 ms` for cropping and resizing the images**.  *(Because I check code in [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) and have low `ram` only check run_time for 5_000 images)*. I repeat each image three times and set the number of indexes in the dataset for using parallelism and select from ofsets for cropping then resizing.

**Creating image dataset for testing benchmark:**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
num_imgs = 5_000
len_ofset = 3
img = np.random.rand(num_imgs, 100, 100, 3)
img_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.tile(img, (len_ofset,1,1,1)), 
                                                  np.repeat(np.arange(len_ofset), num_imgs)))


ofsets_x = np.array([10, 15, 18])
img_w = np.array([10, 12, 15])
ofsets_y = np.array([20, 22, 14])
img_h = np.array([14, 12, 16])

# converting ofsets to tensor for using in tf.function
tns_ofsets_x = tf.convert_to_tensor(ofsets_x)
tns_img_w = tf.convert_to_tensor(img_w)
tns_ofsets_y = tf.convert_to_tensor(ofsets_y)
tns_img_h = tf.convert_to_tensor(img_h)
```

Benchmark in [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/): *(suppose you want to resize images to (16,16))*

```
%%time
size_resize = 16
def crop_resize(img, idx_crop):
    ofset_x = tns_ofsets_x[idx_crop]
    ofset_y = tns_ofsets_y[idx_crop]
    w = tns_img_w[idx_crop]
    h = tns_img_h[idx_crop]
    img = img[ofset_x:ofset_x + w, ofset_y:ofset_y + h, :] 
    img = tf.image.resize(img, (size_resize, size_resize))
    return img

img_dataset = img_dataset.map(
    map_func = crop_resize,
    num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE
    )

next(iter(img_dataset.take(1))).shape
# TensorShape([16, 16, 3])
```

Output:

```
CPU times: user 714 ms, sys: 2.07 s, total: 2.78 s
Wall time: 3.64 s
```